# Installation of Jasmine for Automated testing

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, jasmine

Hope you can help me , I cant seem to find an installation file for jasmine.
I want to learn how to use it, but i can't understand the download and installation process , neither can I find the Zip folder.

Thanks ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jasmine` is available as a `npm` package and as a standalone package [here](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/tree/master/dist). In the standalone version you can find examples how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this one has been answered, here are the steps I took to successfully set up Jasmine on my local box.

- Clone Jasmine - `git clone https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine.git`
- Create a Jasmine directory in your project - `mkdir my-project/jasmine`
- Move latest dist to your project directory - `mv jasmine/dist/jasmine-standalone-2.0.0.zip my-project/jasmine`
- Change directory - `cd my-project/jasmine`
- Unzip the dist - `unzip jasmine-standalone-2.0.0.zip`

Add the following to your HTML file:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.css"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
```

I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/pull/621) to the main project for this to be added to the README.